# Get Youtube publish channel playlist videos in android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

Possible duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648310/get-the-youtube-playlist-and-the-video-id-of-a-channel-in-android) but I can't find the answer for my problem.

I tried to read [Youtube channel document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), but I don't understand how to receive the channel information by its name, for example from [BBC news](http://www.youtube.com/user/bbcnews/playlists) . 
And I tried to follow [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword) in java to search video and I can get the videos list by search term. 
I just  wonder is there any way to get playlists (which contain video `id`) of special public channel by its name, then I can video in playlist by `id`? And do I need to know its id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I can get it by using `Http GET API` from Google. Here is an example for someone need them:
First, I get the `channel id` by using `channel API` like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet&forUsername=bbcnews&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Then I used Search API to get the videos and playlist of this channel by id:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2C+snippet&channelId=UC16niRr50-MSBwiO3YDb3RA&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video%2C+playlist&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it) is the place where you can try `Youtube API`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this request

"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=" + channelId + "&pageToken=" +pageToken + "&key=YOUR_KEY"

Comment: The pageToken parameter identifies a specific page in the result set that should be returned. In an API response, the nextPageToken and prevPageToken properties identify other pages that could be retrieved.